# How to pivot by keeping the index as year and month python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am trying to group values by Year month, from my dataset by using below code

```
pd.to_datetime(All_Insurer_Portal_Reindex['New_Booking/Issued Date']).dt.month.value_counts().sort_index().to_frame()
```

But ending up by getting this PFA screen shot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1rsr.png)

but I am want this type of output PFA screen shot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM8Yv.png)

which code I need to used to achieve this type of output

My data

| New_Booking/Issued Date |
| --- |
| 09-10-2022 |
| 22-09-2022 |
| 10-10-2022 |
| 23-09-2022 |
| 11-10-2022 |
| 09-10-2021 |
| 22-09-2021 |
| 10-10-2021 |
| 23-09-2021 |
| 11-10-2021 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby` with `count` aggregation

```
booking = df['New_Booking/Issued Date']
df.groupby([booking.dt.year, booking.dt.month]).count()
```

Output

```
                                                 New_Booking/Issued Date
New_Booking/Issued Date New_Booking/Issued Date                         
2021                    9                                              2
                        10                                             3
2022                    9                                              2
                        10                                             3
```

If the column is not in `datetime` format, use,

```
df['New_Booking/Issued Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['New_Booking/Issued Date'], dayfirst=True)
```